# How is service validation communicated back to the controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-3

I think I'm missing something fundamental here, but I've been digging for over two hours, and must just be overlooking the obvious.  If so, I apologize.

I have an MVC 3 site, and I have a service layer that my controllers talk to, and a repository that my service layer talks to (all decoupled using an IoC container, but that's irrelevant here).  My domain models are EF4 entities, shared between controller, services, and repositories.

I have a view model for signing up that looks something like this:

```
public class SignupViewModel
{
    [DisplayName("Email")]
    [Required, RegularExpression(@"^.+@.+\..+$")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Password")]
    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Confirm password")]
    [Required, Compare("Password")]
    public string PasswordConfirmation { get; set; }
}
```

My User domain model looks something like this:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public string PasswordSalt { get; set; }
}
```

I have a service method that is used to register the user that looks something like this:

```
public void Register(User user, string planTextPassword)
{
    //Make sure the email address is not taken.
    bool emailIsTaken = IsEmailTaken(user.Email);

    if (emailIsTaken)
    {
        //What do I do here?
    }
    else
    {
        //Create the user.
    }
}
```

And lastly, my controller action to tie it all together:

```
public ActionResult Signup(SignupViewModel signupViewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _accountService.Register(Mapper.Map<SignupViewModel, User>(signupViewModel), signupViewModel.Password);
        _unitOfWork.Commit();
    }

    return View(signupViewModel);
}
```

As you can see in the comment in my service method, what do I do when a service-level validation fails?  As discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637497/validation-of-business-logic-in-asp-net-mvc-using-exceptions), I shouldn't throw exceptions.  But I'm not sure I follow what Ryan is suggesting, or even if that's still applicable (i.e. are there better ways to handle that now with MVC 3, or other tools available now like Fluent Validation).

Like I said, I think I just can't see the forest for the trees at this point, but having spent the last two-three hours trying to figure it out on my own, I thought I may have better luck just asking a question.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I once tried to do what Ryan are talking about. What he says is basically that your service should look something like this:

```
public class TheService{
  ValidationResult Validate(YourType item);
  Save(YourType item);
}
```

The usage would be to first call Validate and if the ValidationResult is successful you call Save. Save would validate the entity again to make sure you aren't forgetting to validate it. The difference is that if there is an error when Save call validate an exception is thrown.

Personally I have done it this way once and won't do it again. I think just throwing an Exception makes everything much clearer and gives you less code to maintain.

To get the error info back to the controller you need to create you own exception. It could look like this:

```
public class RulesException : Exception{
   public IEnumerable<ErrorInfo> Errors {get;set;}
}

public class ErrorInfo{
  public string PropertyName {get;set;}
  public string ErrorMessage {get;set;}
}
```

Something along those lines is a start. For a better implementation look in the source code of [xVal](http://xval.codeplex.com/)

NOTE: If you are going with Exceptions try to avoid writing code where you are doing a try/catch inside a loop. That is the most important thing to avoid when it comes to exceptions as they are more expensive but compared to a database call for example it's cheap.

Comment: This was a good answer.  It was good to hear from somebody that tried both approaches, and your sample will definitely come in handy.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use exceptions, you don't really have any other option than to make your service methods return some sort of rich error message object. Of the arguments in the linked post, the only one I strongly agree with is that exceptions (by themselves) aren't likely to result in good error messages. The thing they have going for them is that they're hard to ignore, so you're very likely to realize you have a problem.

Also, you have to handle exceptions anyhow, because even if you avoid them entirely in your service code, your code isn't the only thing that can cause an exception to be thrown.

That said, rather than having Register have a void return type, you could return an instance of a class that could represent either success or failure, and in the failure case have another property that lists the errors. This is a principled thing to do - it's quite common in languages like Haskell, for instance.